# How do i specify midlet before packaging j2me application?

Tags: java-me, mobile, midlet

i am able to package my application in eclipse.... but when i install application on mobile phone... it says midlet not specified ... so how would set i starting midlet in some settings before packaging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a .jad file in your project. Open that and specify you midlet class.